# Reference request for hyperreal probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

Probabilities usually take values in the interval of real numbers from $0$ to $1$ inclusive. However, has any mathematician developed a theory of probabilities based on a field of hyperreal numbers? For those who don't know, a hyperreal field is a field that satisfies the same first-order sentences as the real field, but which also has infinitesimal and infinitely large numbers. So, the generalization of probability would take values in the interval of hyperreal numbers from $0$ to $1$ inclusive, and some probabilities would be assigned a non-zero infinitesimal. I would be very interested to read some texts where someone develops a theory of hyperreal probability.